# Branching in Apache Airflow using TaskFlowAPI

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-taskflow

I can't find the documentation for branching in Airflow's TaskFlowAPI. I tried doing it the "Pythonic" way, but when ran, the DAG does not see `task_2_execute_if_true`, regardless of truth value returned by the previous task.

```
@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['test'],
)
def my_dag():
    @task()
    def task_1_returns_boolean():
        # evaluate and return boolean value
        return boolean_value
    
    @task()
    def task_2_execute_if_true():
        # do_something...

    outcome_1 = task_1_returns_boolean()
    if outcome_1:
        outcome_2 = task_2_execute_if_true() 


executed = my_dag()
```

What is the proper way of branching in TaskFlowAPI? Should I add one more function specifically for branching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an example DAG in the source code: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f1a9a9e3727443ffba496de9b9650322fdc98c5f/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator_decorator.py#L43.

The syntax is:

```py
from airflow.decorators import task

@task.branch(task_id="branching_task_id")
def random_choice():
    return "task_id_to_run"
```

It was introduced in Airflow 2.3.0.

Comment: I was unaware of this for some reason and I use the TaskFlow API extensively. Is there a list of all @task methods?

Comment: @trench an API reference page for `airflow.decorators` was added starting in version 2.6.0: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.0/_api/airflow/decorators/index.html